# Validate the string which needs to match particular condition(Regular Expression)?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to validate the string, which should not contain any special characters except underscore(_).
For that i have written below code but i was not able to get it through.

```
var string = 'pro$12';
var result = /[a-zA-Z0-9_]*/.test(string);
```

In the above the given string is not valid but i got the result as a true.
Can any body tell what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: All you need is this regex `/^\w+$/`

Answer (score 1):

It returns `true` because, it is able to match `pro`. You can see the actual matched string, with the `match` function, like this.

```
console.log(string.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9_]*/));
# [ 'pro', index: 0, input: 'pro$12' ]
```

Even when it doesn't match anything, for example, your input is '$12', then also it will return `true`. Because, `*` matches 0 or more characters. So, it matches zero characters before `$` in `$12`. (Thanks [@Jack for pointing out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23237220/validate-the-string-which-needs-to-match-particular-conditionregular-expression/23237259?noredirect=1#comment35553508_23237259))

So, what you actually need is

```
console.log(/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$/.test(string));
# false
```

`^` means beginning of the string and `$` means ending of the string. Basically you are telling the RegEx engine that, match a string which has only the characters from the character class, from the beginning and ending of the string.

**Note:** Instead of using the explicit character class, `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, you can simply use `\w`. It is exactly the same as the character class you mentioned.

Quoting from MDN Docs for RegExp,

> #### \w
>
> Matches any alphanumeric character from the basic Latin alphabet, including the underscore. Equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.
>
> For example, `/\w/` matches `'a'` in `"apple,"` `'5'` in `"$5.28,"` and `'3'` in `"3D."`

So, your RegEx can be shortened like this

```
console.log(/^\w*$/.test(string));
```

Comment: It returns `true` because it could also match zero characters ;-)

Comment: @Jack True, but it is Greedy :)

Comment: Hmm yeah, I meant with an input of `$12` it would still return `true` :)

Comment: @Jack Oh that, correct. Updated my answer now. Please check :)